# Docker-compose for flask app -- works except when being used as Pycharm Interpreter

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, pycharm

I am trying to build a development environment for flask app using docker on Windows 10 PC. Currently when I use run the container normally everything works as expected with endpoints accessible on the localhost port (5000) corresponding with the port mapping.
But when I use the docker-compose as an interpreter in Pycharm, something seems to go amiss and no endpoints are accessible on the mapped port; I just get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.
In the terminal of the pycharm debugger, I can use curl to hit flask app endpoints and I can see the application is running correctly.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  archives_app:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app/archives_app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: |
      sh -c "
      mount -t cifs -o 'username=${USERNAME},password=${PASSWORD},domain=${DOMAIN},vers=${VERS}' //ppdo-fs05.ppcou.ucsc.edu/Archive_Data /app/Data/Archive_Data
      mount -t cifs -o 'username=${USERNAME},password=${PASSWORD},domain=${DOMAIN},vers=${VERS}' //PPDO-ACT-RECORD.ppcou.ucsc.edu/PPC_Records /app/Data/PPC_Records
      mount -t cifs -o 'username=${USERNAME},password=${PASSWORD},domain=${DOMAIN},vers=${VERS}' //ppdo-fs05.ppcou.ucsc.edu/Cannon_Scans /app/Data/Cannon_Scans
      flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000 --reload"
    privileged: true
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# Set up Flask application in development mode
ENV FLASK_ENV=development
ENV FLASK_DEBUG=1

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libpango1.0-dev \
    pkg-config \
    smbclient \
    nfs-common \
    cifs-utils \
    sudo \
    curl \
    iproute2 \
    iputils-ping

ENV FLASK_APP=run.py

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app/archives_app

# Mount the Windows Server shares
RUN mkdir -p /app/Data/Archive_Data
RUN mkdir -p /app/Data/PPC_Records
RUN mkdir -p /app/Data/Cannon_Scans
RUN mkdir -p /app/archives_app

COPY .. .

# Expose port 5000 for the Flask application
EXPOSE 5000

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r /app/archives_app/requirements.txt
```

Example of resulting container network settings:

```
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "6bf8276108b961d678271bbe82e504bef7518c93823ea660beca5608d3089dff",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                        "HostPort": "5000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/6bf8276108b9",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "archives_app_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "archives_app-archives_app-1",
                        "archives_app",
                        "77b0c9c6219e"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "ca0adf64ada88dc6002932647f8cb7d20ef63461cc79ce3cbef1d67799e11998",
                    "EndpointID": "5d4365a0cdccadc85c964dfefeb95c5f488ac36ca0a048494c1b3f88c9271489",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.80.1",
                    "IPAddress": "192.168.80.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 20,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:50:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
```

I have mostly tried different port configurations. Also on the host PC I made a listening rule for  port 5000.

**Similar Questions**

[Pycharm Docker port bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207825/pycharm-docker-port-bindings)
...but this is for docker, not docker-compose. Also the ports on my container do appear set up correctly.

[Set PyCharm Python interpreter to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964648/set-pycharm-python-interpreter-to-docker)
Uses outdated process for getting a docker-compose interpreter. Not clear which part of the solution would fix my attempt.